# Дергание элементов при скрытии кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

При нажатии кнопки `"Load More Projects"` подгружаются следующие проекты. Резко подскакивает следующий блок `div` при скрытии кнопки, а `.slideDown()` идет рывками.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".show-more").click(function() {
        $(this).find(".more").first().slideDown(900)
        $(this).find("button").first().css({ "display": "none" });
    })
});
```

Что нужно сделать?

Нашел такой код, но не знаю как его модифицировать:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({height: $(this)[0].scrollHeight}, 200);
});
```

HTML:

```
<section class="profile" id="profile">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cols col-12">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="show-more" style="z-index:99">
                    <button class="button transition" type="submit">LOAD MORE PROJECT</button>
                    <div class="more" style="display:none;">
                        <li>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="cols col-6">
                                    <ul class="cd-item-wrapper">
                                        <li data-type="all" class="is-visible">
                                            <img src="img/portfolio1.png" alt="thumbnail">
                                        </li>
                                        <li data-type="web" class="is-hidden">
                                            <img src="img/portfolio2.png" alt="thumbnail">
                                        </li>
                                        <li data-type="apps" class="is-hidden">
                                            <img src="img/portfolio3.png" alt="thumbnail">
                                        </li>
                                        <li data-type="icons" class="is-hidden">
                                            <img src="img/portfolio4.png" alt="thumbnail">
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="cd-item-wrapper wrapper">
                                        <li data-type="all" class="is-visible">
                                             <h5>Isometric perspective mock-up</h5>

                                        </li>
                                        <li data-type="web" class="is-hidden">
                                             <h5>Time zone app ui</h5>

                                        </li>
                                        <li data-type="apps" class="is-hidden">
                                             <h5>Viro media players ui</h5>

                                        </li>
                                        <li data-type="icons" class="is-hidden">
                                             <h5>Blog/magazine flat ui kit</h5>

                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cols col-6">
                                    <ul class="cd-item-wrapper">
                                        <li data-type="all" class="is-visible">
                                            <img src="img/portfolio1.png" alt="thumbnail">
                                        </li>
                                        <li data-type="web" class="is-hidden">
                                            <img src="img/portfolio2.png" alt="thumbnail">
                                        </li>
                                        <li data-type="apps" class="is-hidden">
                                            <img src="img/portfolio3.png" alt="thumbnail">
                                        </li>
                                        <li data-type="icons" class="is-hidden">
                                            <img src="img/portfolio4.png" alt="thumbnail">
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="cd-item-wrapper wrapper">
                                        <li data-type="all" class="is-visible">
                                             <h5>Isometric perspective mock-up</h5>

                                        </li>
                                        <li data-type="web" class="is-hidden">
                                             <h5>Time zone app ui</h5>

                                        </li>
                                        <li data-type="apps" class="is-hidden">
                                             <h5>Viro media players ui</h5>

                                        </li>
                                        <li data-type="icons" class="is-hidden">
                                             <h5>Blog/magazine flat ui kit</h5>

                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <div style="z-index:99">
                            <button class="button transition" type="submit">NO MORE PROJECTS</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="about" id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1s">
            <div class="cols col-12">
                <div class="title wrapper">
                     <h1>WHAT POEPLE SAY ABOUT US</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="content wrapper">
                     <h5>Our clients love us!</h5>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

`<section class="profile">` содержит кнопку, которая подгружает проекты. При ее нажатии срабатывает `display: none`, и она скрывается. В это время `<section class="about">` подпрыгивает вверх до того места, где начиналась кнопка, а потом плавно появляются новые проекты растягиванием `<section class="profile">`вниз.

Как сделать так, чтобы `<section class="about">` не подпрыгивал? Хотелось бы всё сделать плавно.

Comment: добавил ссылку на сайт в посте выше

Comment: Не заметил никаких рывков в [примере в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pvn691c/). Браузер Opera 30.0.

Comment: как-то не плавно, ну может быть вы и правы.

Comment: а как избавиться от подскакивания нижнего блока, хоть натолкните на идею

Comment: Если проблема в том, что из-за скрытия кнопки всё съезжает вверх, то можно либо скрывать кнопку после анимации: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/2pvn691c/1/), либо использовать `visibility` вместо `display`: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/2pvn691c/2/).

Comment: спасибо, уже близко к решению вопроса, а подскажите еще, а как потом подтянуть вверх все что появилось, понравился метод visibility, но на месте отсутствующей кнопки остается пустое место.
И как вам балы накинуть?

Comment: Объединением обеих версий: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/2pvn691c/3/). Сначала используем `visibility: hidden`, потом (после анимации) `display: none`.

Comment: спасибо!!! как вам балы увеличить? помогли.

Comment: На здоровье. Так как у вас недостаточно репутации, что тихо и неофициально "плюсануть" любой другой мой ответ, то единственный вариант - я могу разместить данный код как ответ, а вы можете принять его как правильный.

Comment: извините и последний, вопросик, а плавно можно чтобы все потом поднялось а не резко. Когда все прорисовалось, появилась кнопка внизу, все вверх резко прыгает... Плавность можно както сюда добавить?

Comment: ок, согласен, разместите, я хочу вам за помощь наградить хоть чем смогу, балами )))

Comment: Попробовал сделать `.slideUp(500)` вместо `.hide()`,но выглядит не сильно лучше: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/2pvn691c/4/).

Comment: да, происходит как то резко, ок, буду думать, спасибо!

Comment: Ответ разместил. Со скрытием кнопки надо что-то эдакое делать. Анимация изменения высоты кнопки до 0 не работает. Возможно, нужны какие-то ухищрения с `margin` или c `position: absolute` и `top`.

Comment: Вместо div class + h1 юзайте a class + font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Улучшенная версия изначального кода. Сначала используем `visibility: hidden` для скрытия элемента, затем, после анимации, `display: none`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".show-more").click(function () {
        var button = $(this).find("button").first();
        $(this).find(".more").first().slideDown(900, function() {
            button.hide();
        });
        button.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    })
});
```

[Полный пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pvn691c/3/).